# Termux Sessions

Tags: terminal, termux

I am trying to see if there is a way to run multiple sessions in Termux
with each session running in a different directory. 
If I run `cd /storage/emulated/0/` in one session
and run `cd $HOME` from my second session,
can I then stay in both directories simultaneously? 
Because running certain packages requires
that I maintain direct contact with `$HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use tmux, screen,  or nohup &